# yarn encore no funciona en WINDOWS

Tags: windows, symfony, yarn

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal, y lo estoy haciendo con mi pc WINDOWS. El caso es que es un proyecto en symfony y me he encontrado con un problema.

- Instalo el symfony encore pack
- instalo yarn

Pero cuando utilizo el `yarn encore dev` me dice lo siguiente

```
yarn run v1.22.5
error Command "encore" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Estos son los pasos que he seguido:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en el siguiente comentario (el mismo error que tienes): https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/251#issuecomment-360779407 podría ser por no tener la versión actualizada. Aunque por la versión que posees parece que si la tienes podrías intentar lo que comenta:

1. Eliminar el directorio `node_modules`, podrías renombrarlo si prefieres.
2. Eliminar el fichero `.lock` de yarn: `yarn.lock`
3. Usar el instalador que proporcionan o el otro método con `choco`: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable (entiendo que ya hiciste un `yarn install`)
4. Ejecutar de nuevo: `yarn add --dev @symfony/webpack-encore`